# PostgreSQL: How to find out which where clause failed

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Consider a properties table with the following columns:

```
id, address, no_of_bedrooms, no_of_bathrooms, garage_size
```

And consider investors table with the following columns:

```
id, name, no_of_bedrooms, no_of_bathrooms, garage_size
```

Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, that an investor is looking for an exact match on no_of_bedrooms, no_of_bathrooms, garage_size on a property.

Now, I can run a query to return a list of investors who would buy a particular property.

What I'd like to know is whether I can use PSQL to find out which investors are NOT interested in a property and which particular attribute(s) that property fails against for each of those investors?

For example, let's say there is a 1bd, 1 bath property, and 4 investors require minimum 2bd, 2 bath home. What query can I run that will give the following output?

```
property_id, investor_id, rejected_column_name
```

In the above result, an investor can have more than 1 row, which means a property got rejected by a particular investor for more than 1 reason.

Is this even possible with SQL/PSQL?

Comment: The property data is precise.  But how do we know if the investors data is less than, mandatory equal, or greater than the value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated the question. For the sake of simplicity, let's say it's an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend unpivoting and then joining at the property level:

```
with ip as (
      select i.*, v.*
      from investors ip cross join lateral
           (values ('no_of_bedrooms', no_of_bedrooms),
                   ('no_of_bathrooms', no_of_bathrooms),
                   ('garage_size', garage_size)
           ) v(prop, val)
     ),
     pp as (
      select i.*, p.*
      from properties ip cross join lateral
           (values ('no_of_bedrooms', no_of_bedrooms),
                   ('no_of_bathrooms', no_of_bathrooms),
                   ('garage_size', garage_size)
           ) v(prop, val)
    )
select ip.id, ip.name, pp.prop, ip.val, ip.name
from pp join
     ip
     on pp.prop = ip.prop 
where pp.id = ? and and pp.val <> ip.val;
```

This assumes that the properties are all strings.  If they have other types, you can convert them with `::text`.